# How to select SPECIFIC data from access database using VB?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, database-connection

I'm new to this kind of programming so I hope someone could help me. The situation is like this:

I just want to select specific row of data from the access database table but I don't know the codes for it.

This code will only return the data from the FIRST ROW of the table.

```
Private Sub cmdshow_Click()

    Open_db
    strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where Student="" & txtstudent.Text & """

    With RS

    txtstudent.Text = !Student
    txtage.Text = !Age

    End With

End Sub
```

The access table is like this:

[image]

So, please help me how to select specific rows of my choice. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: try `strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where Student='" & txtstudent.Text & "'"`  you only need ticks not quotes for text...the textbox has to have a valid existing name or it will return nothing, and if there are lots of rows returned, only the first will show

Comment: @MikeW              Ok. Sorry for the question. Thanks for dropping by.

Comment: @Plutonix      Thanks. It's now returning the value in the first row without error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you would like to pick "Jason" whose ID is 4.

This is the sql statement that you should use.

```
strsql1 = "SELECT * FROM Table 1 WHERE Student = 'Jason';
```

If you like to pick specific rows based on their ID's you can do this

```
strsql1 = "SELECT * FROM Table 1 WHERE ID = 4"
```

Comment: access does not need the semicolon, strings only need ticks, and if ID is a number, then it certainly does not need ticks

Comment: Thats weird, I have always used that way and it works with or without the semicolon.

Comment: yes, it will work, just not needed (and can confuse novices) - the first one has 3 quotes so it would not compile; the second has only one

Comment: Oh that's what you meant. Woops, I usually think that's preassumed knowledge.

Comment: @Manu          I used the strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where ID = 4"   but only returning the first row

Comment: That is weird. Try this "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID = 4"

Comment: @Manu          
Yes, it's more weird now. I commented out the strsql1 part like this: 

Private Sub cmdshow_Click()
    
    Open_db
    'strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where Student='" & txtstudent.Text & "'"
    'strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where ID = '4'"
    
     With RS
    '.AddNew
        
    txtstudent.Text = !Student
    txtage.Text = !Age
    
 
    End With
  
    
End Sub


and the same thing happened, only the first row values are returned

Comment: I wrote those two statements above because either one of those can be used to pull any row from the table.  IF you like to have two selection criteria to pick a/multiple rows then you can just have multiple WHERE conditions. At the moment I think you are using two sql statements in one. Can you please structure the comment so its easy to read.

Comment: I can't structure it in this comment box, maybe I'll post another thread.

Comment: @Manu maybe I'll delete the ( txtstudent.Text = !Student and
    txtage.Text = !Age ) part.. is there ither ways ways to return its values into the textbox?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it in VB. I usually program in C# and prefer to print out any values for debugging purposes in a label box. I think you should get rid of that part for the time being and test it with using the normal statements that I posted up and try print out the values in a label box or console

Comment: @Manu          Ok ill try. How will i print out the values to the label box from database? Sorry for the question. I'm not a programmer.

Comment: Well you store the value that you return from the database into a variable and then display the variable in the label box. label1.text = "This is what i want to display " + myvaraible + "";

Comment: @Manu           retrieveValue = RS(0).Value --- itried this code but didn't work

Comment: Sorry the late reply. I think its better to raise another question and explicitly specify that you are a VB user and you would want blah blah blah.. along those lines. Someone will surely help u out.

Comment: Sorry mate!! Couldn't help you out with VB, not very good at the syntax.